Wordless teaching
Can someone give me a complete commission of wordless teaching (teaching, that does not recall the recollection of what text, (therefore, also, of what text had taught).
How do you compare this to what a computer can do.
Can you encapsulate, expand, embellish, analyze, wordless teaching in phones.
How does it compare?
Please migrate my post to software recommendations stack exchange or patenting stack exchange if more appropriate there.
Thanks.

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure exactly where your interesting question is most appropriate.  I'm thinking perhaps Academia SE is the closest match on Stack Exchange, but I have a hunch it's not a great fit there.  Stack Exchange doesn't currently offer sites for every topic, and does not currently offer a "catch all" question and answer site (although I think it would be a good idea).
If you like, you can ask on Academia SE's meta site if your question, or something similar, would be on-topic there.
I always enjoy reading your questions as you have unique perspectives.
Good luck!
